# Decrypt an tex file encrypted with rand()

Tags: cryptanalysis, random-number-generator, brute-force-attack

[image: Question]

Link to encrypted tex file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gZCujDYmEL-FZ5o_xBUS-Ng5979HSsZ7

This is my attempt at solving the problem:

```
/* The ISO/IEC 9899:1990 edition of the C standard */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>

//#define RAND_MAX 32767
static unsigned long int next = 1;
int rand(void) // RAND_MAX assumed to be 32767
{
    next = next * 1103515245 + 12345;
    return (unsigned int)(next/65536) % 32768;
}
void srand(unsigned int seed)
{
    next = seed;
}

using namespace std;

//Return a byte at a time of the rand() keystream
 char randchar() { 
  static int key;
  static int i = 0;

  i = i % 4;
  if (i == 0) key = rand();
  return ((char *)(&key))[i++];
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {


  for (unsigned int i = time(NULL); i >= 0; i--) //Try all possible return values of time(NULL) since today
  {

      srand(i); 

      cout << "Trying with time(NULL) = " << i << endl;

      FILE *input, *output;
      input = fopen("Homework1b-Windows.tex.enc", "r");
      output = fopen("Homework1b.tex", "w");

      int c,rc, test;
      int pos;
      pos = 0;
      bool pos0, pos1, pos2, pos3, pos4, pos5;
      pos0 = pos1 = pos2 = pos3 = pos4 = pos5 = false;
      char temp1, temp2;

      while ((c = fgetc(input)) != EOF) {
        rc=randchar();
        fputc(c^rc,output);

        test = c^rc;

        temp1 = (char)test;


        temp2 = '\\';

        if ((pos == 0) && (temp1 == temp2))
        {
                 pos0 = true;
        } 

        temp2 = 'd';

        if ((pos == 1) && (temp1 == temp2))
        {
                 pos1 = true;
        }

        /*

        temp2 = 'o';

        if ((pos == 2) && (temp1 == temp2))
        {
                 pos2 = true;
        }

        temp2 = 'c';

        if ((pos == 3) && (temp1 == temp2))
        {
                 pos3 = true;
        }

        */

        temp2 = 'u';

        if ((pos == 4) && (temp1 == temp2))
        {
                 pos4 = true;
        }

        temp2 = 'm';
        if ((pos == 5) && (temp1 == temp2))
        {
                 pos5 = true;
        }

        pos++;

      }
      fclose(input);
      fclose(output);

      if (pos0 && pos1 && pos4 && pos5)
      {
         cout << endl << "Cracked. The seed is time(NULL) = " << i << endl;
         break;
      }
  }

  system("pause");


}
```

I know that the decrypted tex file starts with "\document".

The problem I'm facing is that the code never terminates. It never finds the right key (seed).

Any help?

Thank you.

Comment: Fun fact: the encryption code changes barely 2 bytes out of 4, and has an endianness dependency. So many issues: Starting with a promise of C99 conformance but using C++? Implementing what amounts to a switch statement using tons of variables and code? Overall structure not using an array? Opening/using/closing files in the search loop, rather than buffering the start in memory? Not zeroing `randchar`'s variable `i` at each new decryption attempt? Not opening binary files in "rb" mode under Windows?  No search abort on first failure? Brute force when we have known plaintext?